# curl applied to the fourier transform of a function?

Tags: vectors, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, vector-fields, curl

I am studying Helmholtz decomposition (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition) and it is not clear the part regarding "Another derivation from the Fourier transform", but I think that the problem is not strictly linked with the theorem.

We have a vector field

$\textbf{A}(\textbf{r})$

suppose exists the Fourier Transform $\textbf{G}_{\textbf{A}}(\textbf{k})$  of $\textbf{A}(\textbf{r})$

$\textbf{A}(\textbf{r})$  = $\int \textbf{G}_{\textbf{A}}(\textbf{k}) e^{i \textbf{k} \cdot \textbf{r} } d \textbf{k}$

I don't understand how

$\nabla \times \textbf{A}(\textbf{r})$  = $\int i \textbf{k} \times \textbf{G}_{\textbf{A}}(\textbf{k}) e^{i \textbf{k} \cdot \textbf{r} } d \textbf{k}$

Thanks

Comment: can you do a single partial instead of the whole curl? Then just piece the curl together using e g the expression in terms of the Levi civita symbol

Comment: Try writing with coordinates ;)

Comment: You are right, thank you